# I have a Method invocation 'simpleEditText.getText()' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' error and would like it removed

Tags: java, android

Very new to Android Studio. Working on first app using EditText. I would like to fix the line of code below so I don't get the error: I have a Method invocation 'simpleEditText.getText()' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' error and would like it removed. Any suggestions would be great. I think this means I need to check if simpleEditText has a null value before I getText?

```
/*
 * Retrieve Edit Text Values
 */
    EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLat);
    String strValue = simpleEditText.getText().toString();
```

This is the XML resource associated with editLat:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/lat_hint"
        android:id="@+id/editLat"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textAsset"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

Comment: did editlat is defined in current xml

Comment: Well get the value of edittext on button click so that you can get the value when you perform task

Comment: yes editlat is defined in current xml:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a safety check whenever you initialize something and are unsure whether it'll be null:

```
String strValue;
EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLat);
if(simpleEditText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(simpleEditText.getText())){
    strValue = simpleEditText.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because getText() is an object and may not have a assignment and is null. The difference between primitives and Objects is primitives cannot be null, but have a default value such as a int being 0 and a boolean being false. So when your getting what I assume will be the Text object the only thing you can do is below in code....

```
    /*
     * Retrieve Edit Text Values
     */
    EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLat);
    Text text = simpleEditText.getText();
    String textString;
    if(text != null){
     textString = text.toString();
    } else {
       // Handle missing text object
    }
```

Nothing wrong with null checking and handling. This is your only solution unless you own the android API and and change the library yourself.